# Can not import Pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I am trying to install and use PyGame. I am using Python 3.3.2 and Pygame "3.3 pygame-1.9.2a0" according to the installer. I downloaded it from https://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame/downloads. I used an easy install, and after next-next type install, I opened the Python 3.3.2 Shell and typed "import pygame". I got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    import pygame
ImportError: No module named 'pygame'
>>> import sys; print sys.path
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I am also trying to install it with the PyCharm IDE, but I have NO clue how to do that either. The installer I'm using may be for 32 bit, which wouldn't be compatible with my 64 bit installation of Python, but I don't know how to tell and if so is there even a 64 bit version of PyGame for 64 bit? If anyone knows how to install PyGame for Python 3.3.2 please let me know. Thank you for your time.

Comment: FYI: In Python 3, you have to write `print(...)` instead of `print ...`.

Comment: Import pygame with pip: `py -m pip install pygame`

Answer (score 1):

If your python is a 64 bit version the binary install for the 32 bit will not work. However, there is a 64 bit version here:

http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pygame

If you're worried because they're unofficial don't. I have used many installations from that link for my 64 bit python and they're working great.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, pygame is not available for 64 bit Python (or so it seems on [Pygame Site](http://www.pygame.org/download.shtml)).

The one you installed maybe 32 bit & thus causing the ImportError.

In Python 3.x, print is a function & hence the SyntaxError.

Pycharm for Python 3.x is available [Pycharm Download](http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/download/)

I would recommend using Python 3.x (32 bit) because most of the libraries seem to be compatible with it & also, 64 bit version doesn't provide much performance benefit as such.
I personally use [PyScripter IDE](https://code.google.com/p/pyscripter/)

This maybe very handy at times - [Very useful precompiled binaries for several libraries](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/)

Answer (score 0):

From [pygame website](http://pygame.org/download.shtml):
*windows 64bit users note: use the 32bit python with this 32bit pygame.*
So either donwload a 32bit python, then install with the 32bit pygame installer, or download the unofficial 64bit pygame build at [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pygame).

Answer (score 0):

Ever time I use PyCharm, I go to File > Settings > Project: (project name) > Interpreter > Plus Icon > (search pygame and click install package) This is because I think that you are using a pycharm venv and I think that that isolates outer packages so I do it this way